# AngularJS - get label text for field

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, label

### Question

I was wondering what the AngularJS "best practice" way of getting a label for a field is.  With jQuery you just query using a "label for" query then extract the text.  While it's possible to do it this way with AngularJS, something just doesn't feel right about it.

Assume you have something like this in your HTML:

```
<form name="MyForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label for="MyField">My spoon is too big:</label>
    <input type="text" size="40" id="MyField" ng-model="myField" />

    <br /><br />

    You entered {{ myField }} for {{ myField.label }}
</form>
```

The controller internal is pretty simple:

```
$scope.myField = 'I am a banana.';
```

Basically I want to populate the `myField.label` in the output with "*My spoon is too big.*"

### What I'm Doing Now

All I am doing right now is executing a query that pulls the data similar to the jQuery methodology (`$("label[for='MyField']")`).  Then, if that doesn't exist I am just pulling the placeholder text.  It works, but it seems like a bit of overhead.

### What I'm Trying to Accomplish

I want some custom form validation and I want to include the label in the message.  I just need to pull the label text so that I can write it extremely generically and then not have to worry about people switching i18n data in dynamically later in the game.

### Fiddle

Per the suggested solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/rcy63v7t/7/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You change your HTML to the following:

```
<label for="MyField">{{ myFieldLabel }}</label>
<input type="text" size="40" id="MyField" ng-model="myField" />
```

and your JS to the following:

```
$scope.myFieldLabel = 'My spoon is too big:';
```

then later, you can get/set its value just as easily:

```
if ($scope.myFieldLabel === 'My spoon is too big:') {
    $scope.myFieldLabel = 'New label:';
}
```

Note that new AngularJS best practices call for always using a "dot" in a field reference. It would fit perfectly here if you did something like:

```
<label for="MyField">{{ myField.label }}</label>
<input type="text" size="40" id="MyField" ng-model="myField.value" />
```

and JS:

```
$scope.myField = {
    value: '',
    label: 'My spoon is too big:'
};
```

Then you can always easily access `$scope.myField.label` and `$scope.myField.value`.

Comment: I like that.  This is a great approach as long as people use the JS code for the data lookup.  I guess I'll just write some static code analysis rules that go in and look for people hard-coding labels instead of trying to be too fancy and load the data from the DOM.

Comment: maaaa sppoooon iss tooooo big!

Comment: hahaha is spoon the only thing big here? Jokes apart great code!

Answer (score 3):

Let's say in your controller you have a scope variable like

```
$scope.myField = {};
$scope.myField.label = "Fruit name";
```

and your template is like

```
<form name="MyForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label for="MyField">{{myField.label}}</label>
    <input type="text" size="40" id="MyField" ng-model="myField.value" />
    <br /><br />
    You entered {{ myField.label }} for {{ myField.label }}
</form>
```

By this field label will come dynamically. Apply custom validation in input field as per your requirement.

Hope I understand exactly what you wants.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your label text in the input `title` and you can use a "#" directive.  You can also use this to make sure the label id matches.

```
<label for="{{myfield_control.id}}">{{myfield_control.title}}</label>
<input type="text" size="40" id="MyField" ng-model="myField" title="My spoon is too big:" #myfield_control >

<br /><br />

You entered {{ myField }} for {{ myfield_control.title }}
```

`myField` is your ngModel.  `myfield_control` is a reference to your input control.