# Dynamically display form data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to dynamically display **Person** and **Address** data using label and input value in **Summary Section**. As the user edits the form fields, a list items with label + value should display in the summary tables. If value has been removed in the form, that associated label and value should be removed from the **Summary** Section.

I have added client side validation for each input element. I tried to solve this and couldn't figure out what is best way to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Example:

```js
// the main (app) module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

// add a controller
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.vm = {
    caller: {
      person: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        phoneOne: '',
        email: ''
      },
      address: {
        lineOne: '',
        lineTwo: ''
      }
    }
  };
  $scope.save = function() {
    console.log($scope.vm);
  }
});

// add a directive
myApp.directive('showErrors', function($timeout, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^form',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, formCtrl) {
      // find the text box element, which has the 'name' attribute
      var inputEl = el[0].querySelector("[name]");
      // convert the native text box element to an angular element
      var inputNgEl = angular.element(inputEl);
      // get the name on the text box
      var inputName = inputNgEl.attr('name');
      // only apply the has-error class after the user leaves the text box
      var blurred = false;

      inputNgEl.bind('blur', function() {
        blurred = true;
        el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
      });

      scope.$watch(function(scope) {
        return formCtrl[inputName].$invalid;
      }, function(invalid, scope) {
        // we only want to toggle the has-error class after the blur
        // event or if the control becomes valid
        if (!blurred && invalid) {
          return
        }
        el.toggleClass('has-error', invalid);
      });

      scope.$on('show-errors-check-validity', function() {
        el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
      });

      scope.$on('show-errors-reset', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          el.removeClass('has-error');
        }, 0, false);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.form-group .help-block {
  display: none;
}
.form-group.has-error .help-block {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="claimForm" ng-submit="save()">
    <h3>PERSON</h3>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group form-caller" show-errors>
        <label class="control-label">First Name<span class="help-block" ng-if="claimForm.callerFirstName.$error.required"><i>[required]</i></span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="callerFirstName" ng-model="vm.caller.person.firstName" class="form-control" required="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group form-caller" show-errors>
        <label class="control-label">Last Name<span class="help-block" ng-if="claimForm.callerLastName.$error.required"><i>[required]</i></span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="callerLastName" ng-model="vm.caller.person.lastName" class="form-control" required="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <h3>ADDRESS</h3>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group" show-errors>
        <label class="control-label">Address Line 1<span class="help-block" ng-if="claimForm.addressOne.$error.required"><i>[required]</i></span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="addressOne" ng-model="vm.caller.address.lineOne" class="form-control" required="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group" show-errors>
      <label class="control-label">Address Line 2<span class="help-block" ng-if="claimForm.addressTwo.$error.required"><i>[required]</i></span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="addressTwo" ng-model="vm.caller.address.lineTwo" class="form-control" required="" />
    </div>
     </div>
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
    {{vm | json }}
  </form>
  <h2>Summary</h2>
  <div id="person">
    <h3>PERSON </h3>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div id="address">
    <h3>ADDRESS</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Fiddler URL : http://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/0rttw2wq/4/

Comment: check the firstname & lastname in summary section here: http://jsfiddle.net/ta3e69L0/

Comment: I see you need even label to be printed, I believe in that case your label and value both needs to be bind with the field. Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700715/angularjs-get-label-text-for-field

Comment: @seUser I like this idea but still i think this could be done better way.

Comment: @seUser this is what i came up with using above linked you shared https://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/51hzc753/9/ but i still hate that i have to bring each field as data object.